# Why the correct option is 'unless properly dealt with' rather than others?

Tags: subjects, adverbial-phrases, adverbials

I am practicing an exercise for conditional adverbial clause, there is a hard exercise that makes me confused with all these four options.

> The official soon realized that, ( ), things would get worse.
>
> A. unless dealt with properly
>
> B. if not properly dealing with it
>
> C. unless properly dealt with
>
> D. if dealt not properly with

My question is why C is correct, and there is only a difference of the order of the adverb 'properly' between A and C , as does not matter I think. But why not opt the other except B?

In addition I have known why B is incorrect because the subject of this clause is not 'the official' but 'things'.

Comment: Are you sure this is not a question with more than one correct answer? Could you double-check the instructions please?

Comment: @PPH Yea, my teacher said that is the only answer, I'm also confused with these now.

Comment: Version A (the "correct" one) features "deletion" of "predictably repeated" subject & verb: *...things would get worse, unless [**things were**] dealt with properly*.

Answer (score 3):

Both A and C are correct and I don't think one is preferable to the other. C seems to be more common though.

Comparing the number of Google search results:
"unless dealt with properly": 749
"unless properly dealt with": 2020

Comparing the number of Google Books search results:
"unless dealt with properly": 8 pages
"unless properly dealt with": 17 pages

And see [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unless%20dealt%20with%20properly%2Cunless%20properly%20dealt%20with&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cunless%20dealt%20with%20properly%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunless%20properly%20dealt%20with%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cunless%20dealt%20with%20properly%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunless%20properly%20dealt%20with%3B%2Cc0):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

B is wrong due to the continous tense of "dealing", while the question poses a past tense form - "realized" "would"

A and C should be fine, but C may be slightly better and is used more often.

E.g. of "properly dealt with" being used in this [website](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://mobile-dictionary.reverso.net/en/english-definition/properly%2Bdealt%2Bwith%2Bby&ved=2ahUKEwjqvKeguc_3AhXQzzgGHZp6DiQQFnoECBUQAQ&usg=AOvVaw2vsqvMxU7t_GYnsS5iaX7E)